# How can I search for equations that are displayed as [Equation] instead of the actual equation in a document in Word 365 online?

Tags: office-365, word-online

I use Word online via my Office 365 subscription. I have made an online copy of a Word document containing many equations. For some reasons, some equations got messed up in the process, and appears as:

[image]

instead of showing the actual equation.

How can I search for those equations that shows `[Equation]` instead of the actual equations?

---

I tried searching for `equation` and `[equation]` but that didn't work:

[image]

I went through some of online documentation for Word 365 ([example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/write-an-equation-or-formula-4f799df7-4ca4-4670-afd3-6135768b01d0)) but I haven't seen any solution yet.

---

Clarifications based on the comments written by [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) that the question received ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230928225711/https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5132/why-was-this-question-on-searching-for-equation-in-a-word-365-online-document), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAFJc.png)):

- I am not interested in explanations of why the equation is shown with a gray background and showing [Equation].
- I am not interested in why the find text feature of Word Online is not able to find the questions when I search [Equation].
- I am open to an answer that just says "It's not possible" without explaining why.
- I am  are not looking for any kind of guidance that requires back-and-forth interactions other than the basic spelling grammar and tag improvements alike.
- I am not interesting in anything that requires details not already included in the question and might require you to invest additional time.
- I just want a direct and definite answer based on the information provided in the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, as the advanced search options are not available on Word Online.

Word Online has a subset of the features available on Word for desktop. The Find feature can only search text, contrary to the Find feature of Word for desktop.

Using Word for Desktop instead of Word Online might be your best option. Usually, the edition for Windows is the most complete. Depending on  how the document was converted and other factors you might or might not see the equations on Word by Desktop.

Depending on your subscription, among other things, there might be other workarounds, like the use of plug-ins and JavaScript.

Your screenshot shows that your Word file is hosted on Sharepoint. If you have a managed subscription, you might have ask your subscription admin to learn about the features available for you on Word Online and in Sharepoint.